# Angular 8: Connecting two players together over a singleton service

Tags: html, angular, typescript, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game (Battleships). And the game is working, however i'm trying to make this a multiplayer game. And I've been trying to get two players connected to the same game. But this is not working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have a service which I'm trying to make singleton over all modules and users/sessions

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Player} from '../models/player';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MultiplayerService {

  constructor() { }
  private static _ROOM1PLAYER: Player;
  private static _ROOM1OPPONENT: Player;


  whatsInPlayers() {
    console.log(MultiplayerService.ROOM1PLAYER);
    console.log(MultiplayerService.ROOM1OPPONENT);
  }


  static get ROOM1PLAYER(): Player {
    return this._ROOM1PLAYER;
  }

  static set ROOM1PLAYER(value: Player) {
    this._ROOM1PLAYER = value;
  }

  static get ROOM1OPPONENT(): Player {
    return this._ROOM1OPPONENT;
  }

  static set ROOM1OPPONENT(value: Player) {
    this._ROOM1OPPONENT = value;
  }
}
```

- When i try to add a user to ROOM1PLAYER it works fine.
- When I try to add a user to ROOM1OPPONENT (ON A DIFFERENT PC/SESSION) it still works.

BUT, when i try to call the method whatsInPlayers() to see if both players are populated. I only get to see the one I've added on this session/PC and the other is "undefined".

Can someone guide me in the right direction to be able to get these static variables across all connections/sessions/pcs?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this going to be a local multiplayer or a network multiplayer?

Comment: For now this will be run on my local network. No external connections

Comment: This is simply not possible. You would need a backend service to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `static` from _ROOM1PLAYER & _ROOM1OPPONENT properties, and inside `whatsInPlayers` function replace `MultiplayerService` with `this`.

this property is related to an instance, unlike the static property.

Comment: Unfortunately, did not work. Thanks for the suggestion.